# Use volume name instead of volume ID in Openstack Heat block_device_mapping

Tags: yaml, cloud, openstack, orchestration, heat

The block_device_mapping module can be used to attach storage to an instance. My requirement is to attach an **already existing** bootable cinder volume to an instance using a heat template. The following syntax works,

```
  block_device_mapping:
    - device_name: vda
      delete_on_termination: false
      volume_id : "591aba58-ea89-4982-9adf-a65556351e74"
```

However, is there any way to use the name of the volume instead of the volume UUID?

Comment: OpenStack only supports volume_id. Moreover, the UUIDs are always unique compared to a volume name. https://docs.openstack.org/heat/pike/template_guide/contrib.html#OS::Nova::Server-prop-block_device_mapping